# Can Spring dependencies cause memory issue?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-data

Can Spring Autowiring cause GC issues? Can Spring dependencies any how cause GC to increase?

I had two beans X and Y. Both existed independently and things are stable. When I make X dependsOn Y, then I start observing huge increase in GC count and GC latency.

Things I have tried to find what is the root cause-

- Tried making X depend on Y not through annotation @dependsOn but
  through @autowired. No difference was observered.
- I have made sure that both the beans are of Singleton scope.
- GC logs comparision with and without the change, showed some differences. Major difference was with in MetaSpace in JVM Heap. I am attaching link to GC log reports here. [GC Report with increased GC](http://gceasy.io/my-gc-report.jsp?p=c2hhcmVkLzIwMTgvMDYvMTUvLS1pbmNyZWFzZWQgZ2MgZ2MubG9nLjIwMTgtMDYtMTUtMDEtLTEyLTQ5LTQ=) AND [GC Report of normal state](http://gceasy.io/my-gc-report.jsp?p=c2hhcmVkLzIwMTgvMDYvMTUvLS1ObyBJc3N1ZSBnYy5sb2cuMjAxOC0wNi0xNS0wMC0tMTItNDUtNTA=).

Comment: are you using any other scope than Singleton?

Comment: this is unclear... how about showing the relevant logs?

Comment: @SagarKharab all the beans are of Singleton scope.

Comment: @Eugene I have updated the post with GC log reports.